# CRM Custom Workflow Action - How do you check which input parameter has been passed

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I've got a CWA, that's called from three different workflows - which means I have three different input parameters, all different entities.

How do I check the which has been passed through?

Example 
Input Parameter - Entity A
Input Parameter - Entity B (this one is the calling workflow)
Input Parameter - Entity C

Do you use the CodeActivityContext or input parameters to check this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you have an input parameters like this:

```
[Input("EntityReference A")]  
[ReferenceTarget("account")] 
public InOutArgument<EntityReference> EntityReferenceA { get; set; }
```

Then you can check if its been populated like this:

```
if (AccountReferenceA.Get(context) != null)
{
    //Input A was passed
}
else if (AccountReferenceB.Get(context) != null)
{
    //Input B was passed
}
else if (AccountReferenceC.Get(context) != null)
{
    //Input C was passed
}
```